# Pandas - Multiindex Division [i.e. Division by Group]

Tags: python, pandas

**Aim:** I'm trying to divide each row in a multilevel index by the total number in each group.

**More specifically:** Given the following data, I want to divide the number of Red and Blue marbles by the total number in each group (i.e. the sum across Date, Country and Colour)

```
                         Number
 Date  Country   Colour     
 2011    US      Red      4
                 Blue     6
 2012    IN      Red      9
         IE      Red      5
                 Blue     5
 2013    JP      Red      15
                 Blue     25
```

This would give the following answer:

```
                         Number
 Date  Country   Colour     
 2011    US      Red      0.4
                 Blue     0.6
 2012    IN      Red      1.0
         IE      Red      0.5
                 Blue     0.5
 2013    JP      Red      0.375
                 Blue     0.625
```

Here is the code to reproduce the data:

```
arrays = [np.array(['2011', '2011', '2012', '2012', '2012', '2013', '2013']),
np.array(['US', 'US', 'IN', 'IE', 'IE', 'JP', 'JP', 'GB']),
np.array(['Red', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Blue'])]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(7, 1)*10, index=arrays, columns=['number'])
df.index.names = ['Date', 'Country', 'Colour']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shorter version would be:

```
df.groupby(level=['Date', 'Country']).transform(lambda x: x/x.sum())

                     number
Date Country Colour        
2011 US      Red      0.400
             Blue     0.600
2012 IN      Red      1.000
     IE      Red      0.500
             Blue     0.500
2013 JP      Red      0.375
             Blue     0.625
```

Comment: This is perfect - exactly the answer I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Definitely better.

Comment: @ayhan, Thanks a lot :-)